When do I need COMMIT in Oracle Transaction
In Oracle below code creates Transaction.
But different tutorials say that you also need COMMIT at the beginning and the end.
What is the purpose of this COMMIT when it changes nothing.
What might be examples when using COMMIT makes some difference.
BEGIN

  SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
  
  INSERT INTO PEOPLE(NAME, AGE ) VALUES('John', 20);
  INSERT INTO PEOPLE(NAME, AGE1) VALUES('Bill', 30);

END;


You do not need to COMMIT at the start of a transaction. If you do not COMMIT at the end of the transaction then the transaction will ROLLBACK when it is closed and any changes you made will be undone. Oracle also has implicit transactions - you do not to explicitly start a transaction, it will be automatically started when you use the first statement. When you use a DDL statement (CREATE ..., ALTER ..., etc.) then there will be an implicit COMMIT before the DDL statement and after.

But I am not using COMMIT at the end of the above transaction and the transaction is not ROLLBACK. Records are properly inserted into database. Transaction only rollbacks if there is error in INSERT Statement like referencing non existant AGE1 Column.

The transaction has not finished; a PL/SQL block is not the same as a transaction (you can have many PL/SQL blocks or SQL statements in a transaction). Close the database session and start a new session with the same user and the records will not exist because the transaction has been ended without a COMMIT and the transaction will implicitly be rolled back.

"In Oracle below code creates Transaction." I think that is probably the biggest misconception of the question. Yes, it may create a transaction - but it may not create one if one already exists because you have executed some previous DML statements and then it doesn't create a transaction and will continue using the previous transaction. The transaction also doesn't complete when the database finishes parsing the PL/SQL block - instead it remains open and is used for subsequent statements until the next COMMIT or ROLLBACK or until the database session closes (which implicitly ROLLBACK).
